# how to make a custom viewController with transparent black background?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a viewController appears like the small one in the middle of the picture :

[image: custom viewcontroller]

I tried with the UiAlertView, but it semms not offering this feature.

I found some apps adding buttons and labels, photo in similar viewControllers.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a view controller - it looks like a view that is added as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

The middle View in the image is not a viewcontroller. It is just a custom UIView made up using images and buttons. You can set the transparency of a UIView using property alpha.

Example

```
yourview.alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick replay but, if i set the transparency to 0,5 for example, the all UiView will be semi transparent. You mean i should prepare a custom uiView  with a transparent background image (png) ?

Comment: You can opt both way. You can create a UIView with alpha = 0.5. Then Place a transparent image on that. And for header and close button you can use opaque image. Hope this way you can achieve it. Just Play around this.